# Автоинкремент HierarchyId при заполнении таблицы

Tags: sql-server

Мне необходимо заполнить таблицу **t1**, содержащую колонки **Name(varchar)** и **Hid(hierarchyid)** данными из таблицы **t2**, содержащей колонки **Id(int)** и **Name(varchar)**. При этом необходимо, чтобы **t1.Hid** автоматически инкрементировался при заполнении данными из другой таблицы. Я делаю следующее:

```
DECLARE @hid HIERARCHYID = HIERARCHYID::Parse('/0/');
DECLARE @root HIERARCHYID = HIERARCHYID::Parse('/');
INSERT INTO t1 (Name, Hid)
    SELECT t2.Name, @root.GetDescendant(@hid, NULL) FROM t2
```

Но в итоге получаю t1 с одинаковыми Hid. Это происходит из за того, что в INSERT при добавлении новой записи @hid не меняется, а он должен каждый раз инкрементироваться.

Я получаю это:

```
Name1   /1/
Name2   /1/
Name3   /1/
```

А мне нужно это:

```
Name1   /1/
Name2   /2/
Name3   /3/
```

Есть ли способ, как инкрементировать Hid при использовании его в INSERT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил задачу. Таблица t2 имеет колонку Id. Она имеет уникальные значения. Я поступил следующим образом

```
DECLARE @root HIERARCHYID = HIERARCHYID::Parse('/');
INSERT INTO t1 (Name, Hid)
    SELECT t2.Name, @root.GetDescendant('/' + CAST(t2.Id - 1 AS VARCHAR) + '/', NULL) FROM t2
```

*t2.Id - 1* делал для того, чтоб *t1.Hid* был такой же, как и *t2.Id*